# use sed to change a text report to csv

Tags: sed

I have a report looks like this:

```
par_a
    .xx
    .yy
par_b
    .zz
    .tt
```

I wish to convert this format into csv format as below using sed 1 liner:

```
par_a,.xx
par_a,.yy
par_b,.zz
par_b,.tt
```

please help.

Comment: as long as it is one liner

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `awk:`

```
awk '/^par_/{v=$0;next}/^ /{$0=v","$1;print}' File
```

Or to make it more generic:

```
awk '/^[^[:blank:]]/{v=$0;next} /^[[:blank:]]/{$0=v","$1;print}' File
```

When a line starts with `par_`, save the content to variable `v`. Now, when a line starts with `space`, change the line to content of `v` followed by `,` followed by the `first field`.

**Output:**

```
AMD$ awk '/^par_/{v=$0}/^ /{$0=v","$1;print}' File
par_a,.xx
par_a,.yy
par_b,.zz
par_b,.tt
```

Comment: i suggest you to add this to your solution  `awk '/^[^[:blank:]]/{v=$0} /^[[:blank:]]/{$0=v","$1;print}' file` .

Comment: I'd put a `next` into the first action block rather than repeat the pattern, but that's a style question. Is it guaranteed that the lines contains only one field, though? (Oh, and some commonly shipped versions of mawk don't know POSIX character classes like `[[:blank:]]`, so if your awk complains about it, use `\s`. That is nonstandard, but mawk understands it.)

Comment: Wintermute:  hope so.. else can replace $1 with $0 (if couple of spaces doesn't matter)..

Comment: `sub(/^[[:blank:]]*/, ""); print v "," $0` should cover that case (`\s` if mawk).

Answer (score 4):

With sed:

```
sed '/^par_/ { h; d; }; G; s/^[[:space:]]*//; s/\(.*\)\n\(.*\)/\2,\1/' filename
```

This works as follows:

```
/^par_/ {               # if a new paragraph begins
  h                     # remember it
  d                     # but don't print anything yet
}
                        # otherwise:
G                       # fetch the remembered paragraph line to the pattern space
s/^[[:space:]]*//       # remove leading whitespace
s/\(.*\)\n\(.*\)/\2,\1/ # rearrange to desired CSV format
```

Depending on your actual input data, you may want to replace the `/^par_/` with, say, `/^[^[:space:]]/`. It just has to be a pattern that recognizes the beginning line of a paragraph.

**Addendum:** Shorter version that avoids regex repetition when using the space pattern to recognize paragraphs:

```
sed -r '/^\s+/! { h; d; }; s///; G; s/(.*)\n(.*)/\2,\1/' filename
```

Or, if you have to use BSD sed (as comes with Mac OS X):

```
sed '/^[[:space:]]\{1,\}/! { h; d; }; s///; G; s/\(.*\)\n\(.*\)/\2,\1/' filename
```

The latter should be portable to all seds, but as you can see, writing portable sed involves some pain.

Comment: i'm trying to figure out the first sed command but i can't . I confused so much with the hold space and pattern space. Could you explain me a bit? The part confuses me was, before doing the replacement `s/\(.*\)\n\(.*\)/\2,\1/`, how the pattern space looks like. I know sed will do the replacement only on the pattern space. PS = `.zz\npar_a` ? ie, the current line would be on the top?

Comment: Yes. `G` takes the contents of the hold buffer (the last `par` line) and appends it to the pattern space (the current line). Sort of like `H` in reverse.

Comment: `H` means to take the contents of the pattern space and append it to the hold buffer. Separated by a newline in both cases.

Comment: Just like awk with a default `RS`, sed processes lines individually. A line is read into the pattern space, on which most commands operate, then the code is executed, then the next line is read into the pattern space, and so forth. In addition to the pattern space, you have the hold buffer, which is just a buffer on the side where you can remember stuff, and a few commands that move stuff around between the pattern space and hold buffer. In the code above, I use `h` and `G`; `h` overwrites the hold buffer with the pattern space, and `G` appends the hold buffer to the pattern space.